# Are Hardcore characters gone forever if they die in PvP?

Tags: diablo-iii

Now that the PvP aspect of Diablo 3 has been released, are Hardcore characters able to compete (they don't have access to the real money auction house, so I was curious)?  And if they are able to, if they die, will they be gone forever similar to campaign play?

Comment: This question came too early, nothing is certain until the release of PvP. I voted to close, it can be reopened eventually later on.

Comment: @Drake Out of curiosity, why were the questions that came prior to the release of D3 allowed, but one concerning PvP prior to its release closed?  Also, how do you re-open a question? I've never done that before.

Comment: Because Diablo 3 has a long beta phase with literally "thousands" of users (not as much as Dota 2 but still many). When Blizzard will open a beta phase of Diablo 3 PvP we can reconsider this question.

Comment: @Drake And how would I re-open this question?

Comment: @SirCobalt I believe you can get moderator attention by flagging your question, but please wait until PvP has been released since until that time this is speculation about the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the addition of brawling in [Patch 1.0.7](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/1-0-7), the [Player vs Player section](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/pvp) was added to the Game Guide, which states:

> When you die in the Chapel, you’ll reappear there (even if you’re a hardcore character, your death isn’t permanent). You won’t lose any equipment durability for participating (or perishing) in a brawl.

So, no, hardcore characters are not lost!

Answer (score 6):

Blizzard's current position, which will presumably hold until PvP's release, is that due to the rapid death nature of the arena, hardcore characters will not be permanently dead when they die in the PvP arena.

[According to the Diablo Wiki, a quote from Wyatt Cheng in an interview](http://www.diablowiki.net/Hardcore):

> Wyatt Cheng: Our current position is that you don’t die in PvP in Hardcore mode. So what happened in Diablo II is that anyone who wanted to do Hardcore PvP would basically level a character to level 10, and then they’d find another level 10 character, and they’d fight and one would die. That’s just not really that interesting. So we’re just going to let players engage in PvP.

Comment: PVP has now been released under the name "Brawling." Could you please update or delete your answer to reflect this addition?